# Deriving weight formula for exponential moving average

Tags: numerical-methods, average

According to [this](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Moving_Average) and many other places, weight for exponential moving average is just being defined as $\omega_t=(1-\alpha)\alpha^t$, where $t$ is current index and $\alpha$ is a smoothing factor.

How does one derives this formula itself and what does $\alpha$ mean, and where does one can plug size of averaging window?

This is the problem for me as I expected $\omega$ to be a function of window size $N$ and index $t$, but here and everywhere else I got only $t$ and mysterious $\alpha$.

I understand that $0<\alpha<1$ and that it describes the steepness of the exponential slope, but I am confused that I cant find the derivation of this formula. That is why I cant understand it to the end. Could anybody provide step by step derivation of this?

Answer (score 1):

With exponential moving average, your averaging window includes all previous values, although most recent values weight more. 
A finite w can not thus be defined in this case.

On the other hand, you can select $\alpha$ so that the last w samples make up for a given portion of your current estimate.

In your discrete case, an $\alpha$ value such that the last w samples make up for about 62.3% of the current estimate would be:

$$
\alpha = 1 - e^{(-1/w)}
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Time_Constant

Answer (score 0):

The weight can be derived when you view the EMA (Exponential Moving Average) update as a difference equation:

$$
y_t = \alpha y_{t-1} + (1-\alpha) x_t
$$

Here, $(1-\alpha)$ is a measure of how much you "trust" the new observation $x_t$: the higher $\alpha$, the more you tend to stick to the accumulated average $y_{t-1}$, and the less the impact $x_t$ has on the new average $y_t$.

In a usual average of two quantities their weights are equal to $1/2$:

$$
\operatorname{avg}(y_{t-1}, x_t) = \frac{y_{t-1} + x_t}2
= \frac12 y_{t-1} + \frac12 x_t
$$

With EMA, you use $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ for more precise control of the balance between $y_{t-1}$ and $x_t$.

One can solve this difference equation to obtain the solution which is (almost) the weighted sum as in the question.

### Solving the difference equation

The difference equation of the EMA can be solved like this. First, manually calculate $y_t$ for a few values of $t$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= \alpha y_0 + (1-\alpha) x_1\\
y_2 &= \alpha y_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2 = \alpha^2 y_0 + \alpha(1-\alpha) x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2\\
y_3 &= \alpha y_2 + (1-\alpha) x_3 = \alpha^3 y_0 + \alpha^2(1-\alpha) x_1 + \alpha (1-\alpha) x_2 + (1-\alpha)x_3\\
\end{aligned}
$$

It looks like the formula for $y_t$ goes something like this:

$$
y_t = \alpha^t y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^t \alpha^{t-i} (1-\alpha) x_i
$$

Alternatively, you can let $i$ represent the power of $\alpha$, so the formula becomes:

$$
y_t = \alpha^t y_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \alpha^i (1-\alpha) x_{t-i}
$$

Finally, use induction to prove that this solution is correct:

1. Base case: $y_0=\alpha^0 y_0 + 0$ is true.
2. Assume $y_t$ is true. Show that $y_{t+1}$ satisfies the difference equation:

$$
\begin{split}
y_{t+1} &= \alpha y_t + (1-\alpha) x_{t+1}\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + \alpha\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \alpha^i (1-\alpha) x_{t-i} + (1-\alpha) x_{t+1}\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + \alpha (1-\alpha) (\alpha^0 x_t + \alpha^1 x_{t-1} + \dots + \alpha^{t-1} x_{1}) + \alpha^0 (1-\alpha) x_{t+1}\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + (1-\alpha) (\alpha^1 x_t + \alpha^2 x_{t-1} + \dots + \alpha^{t} x_{1}) + \alpha^0 (1-\alpha) x_{t+1}\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + (1-\alpha) (\alpha^0 x_{t+1} + \alpha^1 x_t + \alpha^2 x_{t-1} + \dots + \alpha^{t} x_{1})\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + (1-\alpha) \sum_{i=0}^{t} \alpha^i x_{t+1-i}\\
&= \alpha^{t+1}y_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{t} \alpha^i (1-\alpha) x_{t+1-i}
\end{split}
$$

Indeed, we get the same formula as for $y_t$, but with $t+1$ instead of $t$ everywhere, so the solution is correct.

### The weight

Looking at the formula again:

$$
y_t = \alpha^t y_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \alpha^i (1-\alpha) x_{t-i}
$$

...we see that it's of this form:

$$
\begin{cases}
y_t &= \alpha^t y_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} w_i x_{t-i}\\
w_i &= (1-\alpha) \alpha^i
\end{cases}
$$

...where $i$ is the current index and $\alpha$ is the smoothing factor, just like in the question.

### Practical consideration

In practice we don't know the initial condition $y_0$ because we only observe $y_t$ starting from $t=1$. However, the weight of $y_0$ is $\alpha^t$, which quickly goes to zero when $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, so one can safely ignore the initial condition and use the sum as the average:

$$
y_t \approx \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \alpha^i (1-\alpha) x_{t-i}
$$